# Problems Generating URLs from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, mysql

I am trying to generate several links by grabbing values from a database.
I can connect to the database with out any problems, and I can pull the variables without any problems, but when I try to generate my html code, everything turns to gibberish.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//Generate carousel
var mymovies = "<div id='tumbnailtest' class = 'carousel'><ul><li><a href='watchmovie.php?path=";
for (var i = 1; i < 10; i++){
    <?php
    //Get movie List
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT Title, Filepath, Posterpath FROM movies WHERE ID = $count");
    while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
        //for generating url
        $mpath = $row["Filepath"];
        $mmname = $row["Title"];
        $ppath = $row["Posterpath"];
        $count = $count + 1;
    }
    ?>
    mymovies += "<li><a href=watchmovie.php?path=<?php echo $mpath;?>"
    mymovies += "&mname=<?php echo $mmname;?><img src=<?php echo $ppath;?> width='200' height='300' border='0' style='padding: 0 0px 0 0px;' title='<?php echo $mmname; ?>'></a></li>";
    }
    mymovies += "</ul></div>";
document.write(mymovies);

</script>
```

The link ends up looking like this

```
<a href="watchmovie.php?path=&lt;li&gt;&lt;a href=watchmovie.php?path=Movies/iRobot.mp4&amp;mname=iRobot&lt;img src=images/iRobot.jpeg width=" 200'="" height="300" border="0" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;" title="iRobot"></a>
```

When it should end up looking like this

```
<li><a href='watchmovie.php?path=<?php mname ?>&mname=<?php echo $mname;?>' target="_blank"><img id='' src='<?php echo $ppath; ?>' width="200" height="300" border="0" style="padding: 0 0px 0 0px;" title="<?php echo $mname; ?>"></a></li>
```

Where mname is iRobot when $count = 1. Where is this extra <li><a href=watchmovie.php?path= coming from? It seems like I am getting random garbage written into my link.

Updated File Here.

```
<?php
//connect to database server
$row;
    $dbcnx1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "wouldntyouliketoknow");
    if (!$dbcnx1){
        echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the database server at this time.</P>" );
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo( "<P>Successfully connected to the database!</P>" );
    }
    //select database
    mysql_select_db("movies", $dbcnx1);
    if (! @mysql_select_db("movies") ) {
        echo( "<P>Unable to locate the movies database at this time.</P>" );
        exit();
    } else {
        echo( "<P>Successfully connected to the movies database!</P>" );
    }
    //Get movie List
    $count = 1;
?>
<html>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/JMyCarousel.css" />
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/scollingcarouselunminified1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tumbnailtest').scrollingCarousel({
    autoScroll: false
    });
});
</script>
<?php
$mymovies = "<div id='tumbnailtest' class = 'carousel'><ul>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; i++) {
//Get movie List
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Title, Filepath, Posterpath FROM movies WHERE ID = ".$i);
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    //for generating url
    $mpath = $row["Filepath"];
    $mmname = $row["Title"];
    $ppath = $row["Posterpath"];
}
$mymovies .= "<li><a href='watchmovie.php?path=".$mpath;
$mymovies .= "&mname=".$mmname."'><img src='".$ppath."' width='200' height='300' border='0' style='padding: 0 0px 0 0px;' title='".$mmname."'></a></li>";
}
$mymovies .= "</ul></div>";
echo $mymovies;
?>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the <strike>JS</strike> code to:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/JMyCarousel.css" />
</head>
<body>
<?php
//connect to database server
$row;
    $dbcnx1 = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "wouldntyouliketoknow");
    if (!$dbcnx1){
        echo( "<P>Unable to connect to the database server at this time.</P>" );
        exit();
    }
    else{
        echo( "<P>Successfully connected to the database!</P>" );
    }
    //select database
    mysql_select_db("movies", $dbcnx1);
    if (! @mysql_select_db("movies") ) {
        echo( "<P>Unable to locate the movies database at this time.</P>" );
        exit();
    } else {
        echo( "<P>Successfully connected to the movies database!</P>" );
    }
?>
<script type='text/javascript' src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='js/scollingcarouselunminified1.js'></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#tumbnailtest').scrollingCarousel({
    autoScroll: false
    });
});
</script>
<?php
$mpath;
$mmname;
$ppath;
$mymovies = "<div id='tumbnailtest' class = 'carousel'><ul>";
for ($i = 1; $i <= 10; $i++) {
//Get movie List
$result = mysql_query("SELECT Title, Filepath, Posterpath FROM movies WHERE ID = '".$i."'");
while ( $row = mysql_fetch_array($result) ) {
    //for generating url
    $mpath = $row["Filepath"];
    $mmname = $row["Title"];
    $ppath = $row["Posterpath"];
}
$mymovies .= "<li><a href='watchmovie.php?path=".$mpath;
$mymovies .= "&mname=".$mmname."'><img src='".$ppath."' width='200' height='300' border='0' style='padding: 0 0px 0 0px;' title='".$mmname."'></a></li>";
}
$mymovies .= "</ul></div>";
echo $mymovies;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

<strike>There still is a problem with the JS and PHP though, you cannot mix it like this to achieve what I think you are trying to do...</strike> But try this and see if it works :)

Comment: Much better! Thankyou! However, <img is still being included in the hyperlink portion instead of being part of the html code.

Comment: Awwww yeah! You are the best.

Comment: Even though that answered my original question, I do have another. Why is it not progressing my count? I should have more than just 10 links to iRobot. It works if I do each statement several times outside the loop, why does it not work inside the loop?

Comment: It's because you mixed JS and PHP, the program needs to be changed so that PHP is being looped, not JS. (It's complicated, I know...) Should I try to fix that to?

Comment: If you would be willing, that would be awesome. I am fairly new to php and js.

Comment: Hmmm... not quite, now nothing loads on the page. Which is odd because I should have two echo messages pop at the top letting me know that I was able to connect to my database.

Comment: If this PHP code is double-wrapped (<?php<?php) it won't work, try the code without <?php and ?>

Comment: Updated question with full file, not double wrapped.

Comment: Still generating a blank page.

Comment: Still a no go. The page loads until I uncomment this line: $result = mysql_query("SELECT Title, Filepath, Posterpath FROM movies WHERE ID = ".$i);

Comment: IDs are numeric aren't they? And they are 1-10?

Comment: Ah, found it, one of the i's in the for loop needed a $.

Comment: Thankyou so much for helping me out for so long!

Comment: You're welcome, debugging is hard work. Thanks for finding that bug, have a great day!